# Why does my Google Earth flicker?

Tags: google-earth

When using Google Earth, when I pan the map the application flickers white randomly.
The full window turns white for a very short time and I can see "Not Responding" flicker in the title bar.

Why does Google Earth flicker and what can I do about it?

MS Windows 7 64-bit
Intel Core i7 720QM
4.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3-1333
CLEVO CO. W870CU
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 285M
320GB Seagate Momentus 7200.3

The drivers are up-to-date and the temperatures are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the steps listed in Google Earth's support article:
[Resolving Crashing and Graphics Issues on Windows Machines](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176180)

Although some of the steps you have already done, here is the complete list without details:

Step 1: Clearing Your Cache
Step 2: Turning Off Atmosphere
Step 3: Switching Between DirectX and OpenGL
Step 4: Determining which Graphics Card You Have
Step 5: Updating Your Graphics Card Drivers
Step 6: Updating DirectX Drivers
Step 7: Removing a Corrupt myplaces.kml File

Comment: I didn't find it when I first went through the steps, but turning off Atmosphere in the View menu helps a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try going into Google Earth, and click Tools -> Options and in the 3D View, try switching between OpenGL / DirectX, or modifying some of the other settings such as Antialiasing.

If nothing else, this could very well be a bug in the graphics drivers you are using.

Comment: Tried changing colors, OpenGL/DirectX, Anti-Aliasing, Anisotropic, ... :-(

Comment: Resize the window too. If it's worse with a larger window then that would reinforce the idea that your display drivers are at fault.

Comment: Is it only an issue in this app?  Do you use other programs that use OpenGL or Direct3d like games?  Have you tried running something else using the 3d mode in windowed view instead of fullscreen?

Comment: Reinstalled another last version of the drivers too... It is only an issue with this application. Other applications and full-screen games don't show such issues... Running it in a smaller window does not show the issue, but I want to run it in maximized...